# Xcode tmp/strip error when trying to make an archive

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am working on a project written in AngularJS, Cordova, and Ionic.

When I try to build my project in XCode to put on the apple store I get this error:

```
Strip /Users/swdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Self_Service-dmwurawdbtvnmpgdsjvsyxoxafvo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Self\ Service/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libCordova.a (in target 'CordovaLib' from project 'CordovaLib')
    cd /Users/swdev/Documents/SelfServiceApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -S -T /Users/swdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Self_Service-dmwurawdbtvnmpgdsjvsyxoxafvo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Self\ Service/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libCordova.a

fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: can't open temporary file: /tmp/strip.AH03t9 (No such file or directory)
Command Strip failed with a nonzero exit code
```

ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic1 1.3.5
@ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.0.1
Cordova Plugins : no whitelisted plugins (15 plugins total)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run : 0.2.5

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/swdev/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy : 1.9.4
ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.11.3
OS : macOS Catalina
Xcode : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11A420a

cordova requirements
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 11.0
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.4
CocoaPods: installed 1.8.0

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors when you do `ionic cordova prepare ios`?

Comment: No, no errors. It appears to be an XCode thing only.

Comment: I'm sure you've already tried, but if not, the only other thing I do when I get an unexplained issue is to remove the platform and add it again. My process is `ionic cordova platform remove ios`, then remove the `plugins` folder (`rm -r ./plugins`), then `ionic cordova platform add ios`, and finally `ionic cordova prepare ios`.

Comment: @JohnTiggernaught I tried that and there was no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that /tmp folder exists and you have writing permission

Comment: adding some more details,

The answer works. I am adding some more details on the answer. I had to set both Read & write permission to the /private/tmp folder or /tmp syslnk in the root path. i.e. machd path. for everyone user